# SQL Server 2014 How to store time intervals between inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm working in SQL Server 2014 and am trying to create a column to store the interval between SQL inserts. How can I do this? I'm inserting amperage values from several sensors with one insert statement. I'd like the table to look like the attached picture.

[image: Amperage table]

Comment: Your sample data makes no sense.  Where does 14 come from?  What's wrong with just using the `timestamp` column?

Comment: Sorry. 14 would be the number of seconds between each insert. It's an arbitrary number.

Comment: I reloaded a better image with correct second intervals.

Comment: As interval column can be generated later based on TimeStamp column, why would you calculat it during insert. Maybe you can achieve this by `- MAX(TimeStamp)` before inserting, but things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lag()` to calculate this when you need it:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp), timestamp
               ) as diff_in_seconds
from t;
```

You don't need to do this when the table is created.

Comment: I have used lag but with thousands of records and multiple sensors, the query takes very long.

Comment: @JaySettle do you have index on TimeStamp?

Comment: I do not. I will try that.

Comment: With timestamp indexed I have the following:700 rows takes 1 second.
2000 rows takes 11 seconds.
6000 rows takes 19 seconds.

Comment: @JaySettle . . . This question doesn't specify anything about sensors.  You should ask *another* question that includes full information about what you want to do, the query you are using, and the indexes that you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

1. Add new field called internal to the table and make update query to update this field " Interval"
2. For new records do the following

   - Find the last inserted record by `top(1) and order by timestamp desc`
   - Insert the new record with setting the value of `Iterval = now - lastinserted.TimeStamp`

this solution will cost time on updating the existing records but on inserting, you are querying the db to get the last inserted, then you are sending to the db the data updated, but this solution will be better on data that exceed 100 of thousands of records

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks i like this. Are you suggesting a stored procedure that gets run on each insert? That could work, but I'm concerned about scaling... the stored procedure having to find the "max" time stamp for that sensor which is actually a join to another sensor table. If I have thousands of microcontrollers with multiple sensors with thousands of records will it take longer the more records it has to search through?

Comment: you don't need to find the max, you will get the last inserted record since it will hold the max timestamp